# Digital Picture Frame as Monitor for RPI 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have an old Digital Picture Frame and I want to use its LCD display for my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.
I already opened the Digital Frame and the display is a LCD display with a 50 pin connector.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do that?

Thank You